# Cordova в Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, phonegap, cordova

Добрый день!

Хочу научиться делать нативные приложения JS, HTML под android. Подскажите, в Visual Studio Community 2015 есть ли пакет Cordova?

Есть ли еще способы легко собирать приложения?

Пробовал:

- build.phonegap.com - собирает только под винду, под остальным ошибки
- в консоли я испытываю сильную боль и ошибки
- PhoneGap Desktop - может я сильно критичен, но без build - это как зажигалка без газа

Comment: *нативные* поумолчанию противоположно *JS, HTML*. Нативные приложения для Android пишутся только на Java (C++)

Answer (score 1):

Есть [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx) - поддерживаются платформы Android, iOS (remote build), Windows, wp8.